# How to define Entry User name/Password/FirstName/LastName in Xamarin From so android will auto fill it?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I know Android from certain version can detect the field is a field to enter User Name/ Password / Last Name / First Name?

But what I need to do in Xamarin Form for that to be happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In API-27+ (Oreo+) it is preferable to use an `AutoCompleteTextView` with the Autofill Framework but not absolutely needed.

Note: `Xamarin.Forms` currently (up to `3.0.x`) does not implement the Android native `AutoCompleteTextView` in any of the built-in Forms' controls but you can use just an `Entry` control (implemented as a `TextView` on Android).

On either your Android-based `TextView` or `AutoCompleteTextView` you should programmically call:

```
* SetAutofillHints
* ImportantForAutofill
```

Example:

```
usernameView.SetAutofillHints(new string[2] {"emailAddress", "userName"});
usernameView.ImportantForAutofill = ImportantForAutofill.Yes;
```

Note: In native `Xamarin.Android` you can just set these attributes in the AXML layout.

re: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/optimize-autofill/#0

Note: Review the Android docs for the basics on what the `AutofillHints` strings should be set to...

In `Xamarin.Forms` you can do this via a custom renderer or an effect:

#### `Xamarin.Forms` Auto-fill Android Effect Example:

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("EffectsAutoFill")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(AutoFillUserNameEffect), "AutoFillUserNameEffect")]

namespace Effects
{
    public class AutoFillUserNameEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            var textView = (TextView)Control;
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                textView.SetAutofillHints(new string[2] { "emailAddress", "userName" });
                textView.ImportantForAutofill = ImportantForAutofill.Yes;
            }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
emailEntry.Effects.Add(Effect.Resolve("EffectsAutoFill.AutoFillUserNameEffect"));
```

Your Forms' app will now trigger whatevery auto-fill service the user have enabled on their device: Google, LastPass, etc.... (of course it is up to the user to enabled one or not...)

#### Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!! Maybe off the topic a little bit, I am not familiar with iOS (I don't even use iOS myself).  Do they have similar feature that I can implement?

Comment: @KingChan iOS 11 added one: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill?changes=latest_minor